# Oracle ADF : Select Check box at row level giving issue while selecting in panel tabbed

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-adf

I am referring to this blog.
http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2010/05/yes-no-check-box-in-query-criteria.html
however my requirement is different. I have multiple tabs where multiple tables are present. In each table row I need a column attribute is_active in checkbox format. So basically I want to store active or non active setup lines through panel tabbed screens.

With above blog approach first tab is working fine for checkboxes, but the second , third and other tabs are having below issues in check box.

When selected one checkbox, let's say it is checked, other checkboxes in all rows gets checked.

I checked the binding it is bind to it's respective attributes and VO iterators in pagedefinition, I chceked the code for model and view layer for working and non working tab.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue is solved when created a transient attribute with control type checkbox, that transient attribute will be contolling the is_active value.